# Sign up and log in, Express, React, Node, Psql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, authentication

I am trying to create signup and Login for the first time with express and react using PostgreSQL. My post works just fine. A user can be added to the database so I jumped into handling duplicates. 
I am using the findUserByEmail function to find my email and then, in my routes, create the user if it does not exist.

I tried everything and still is giving me problems. I manage to get it working by just returning the query, without a response, which I don't think is right:

```
const findUserByEmail = (req, response) => {
  return pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [req.body.email])
};
```

Although, I need the response to handle the errors.

The way that I found more common and is how I am trying is:

```
const findUserByEmail = (req, response) => {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [req.body.email]),
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      response.json(results.rows);
    };
};
```

And when I call it here:

```
app.post("/signup/user", (req, res, next) => {
  queries
    .findUserByEmail(req, res)
    .then(user => {
      if (user.rows.length > 0) {
        res.status(400).send("this email is already in use");
      } else {
        queries.createUser(req.body, res);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    });
});
```

But the error is:

`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

If anybody can give me a hand cause I've been 2/3 weeks just for the authentication.
I'll leave my repo if anybody wants to have a look, is a bit messy though.
https://github.com/jaitone/CRUD-in-JS

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `pg` as part of your project. then:

```
const findUserByEmail = (req, response) => { // send just email instead
  return pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [req.body.email])
};
```

Is completely legal and beautiful. The library creates a promise and returns it.

> I manage to get it working by just returning the query

It is not returning the query, it is returning the mechanism to run the query in a promise wrapper(to be run in the future). So when you do `.then` it will actually execute and return the result. BUT

**If you want to do it manually:**

In the `findUserByEmail` you are not returning a `Promise`, instead you are just ending the request chain by saying `res.json`(which in turn means you are returning `undefined`).

You can create a `Promise` wrapper or use [`util.promisfy`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to make the `pool.query` a promise.

```
const findUserByEmail = (req, response) => { // send just email instead
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [req.body.email]),
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      resolve(results.rows);
    };
  });
};
```

**Note,** sending the `email` instead of whole `req` and `res` objects is a good idea.

Comment: ok, so I should just leave by returning. Which is how I had it. I thought i need it a response so I could handle the errors and inform the user.

Comment: can you tell me (or push) the changes that you made? there is very little chance that wouldn't work

Comment: also if you are sending the `email` then use `[email]` not `req.body.email`

Comment: I just pushed it

Comment: I am just returning now and the error is: `_http_outgoing.js:470
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)`

Comment: Yes because in the create user part u just messed up again.

Comment: Yes, I just fixed that!

Comment: `resolve` is not `response`.. also don't do `response.json` in createUser, use `resolve` and reject instead. Also, Please read about Promises.